# How to make post request call to Facebook Graph Api using Httparty in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to build a bot for Facebook Messenger. I have to post request call to Facebook Graph Api. Sample code they gave is in node.js. I am using rails as my backend.

**Sample Code**

```
request({
    uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
    qs: { access_token: PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
    method: 'POST',
    json: messageData
});
```

I am using Httparty gem for making post requests.Problem is i don't know what is **qs** in request. So how should i give **qs** information to facebook ? Help me to convert above sample code into rails code.

Comment: did I answer you? If yes, please mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**qs** means query string. So actual url to hit is   **https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token={access_token}.**
This is can be bit with **httparty** by setting query value in option with **access_token**.
**Example :-**

```
options ={
            "query": {access_token: @page_access_token},
            "body": message_data
        }
HTTParty.post("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages",options)
```

Answer (score 0):

`qs` is the query_string, you can just append it to the url.
see the below ruby sample code.

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

ACCESS_TOKEN = "<YOUR ACCESS TOKEN>"

url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=" + ACCESS_TOKEN
SENDER_ID = <YOUR SENDER ID>
MESSAGE = "<YOUR SENDING STRING>"

options = {
        body: {
                recipient: {id: SENDER_ID},
                message: {text: MESSAGE}
        }
}

result = HTTParty.post(url, options)
print result
```

However there are also some sample codes of messenger bot written in RoR, check them on github.